# socketpair() opens socket ends as read only?

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on some inter-process communication and I'm using socketpairs for a bit of it.  I've run into some strange behavior that I unfortunately haven't been able to replicate with a short bit of code.  I'm opening a pair of sockets in the standard way:

```
// setup a socket for read/write functionality
if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds) < 0) {
   <handle error>
}
```

But when I go to look at the /proc/[pid]/fd folder of my process:

```
total 0
dr-x------ 2 user user  0 May 14 16:37 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 8 user user  0 May 14 16:37 ../
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 1 -> /dev/pts/4
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 10 -> pipe:[19185636]
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:37 11 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 12 -> socket:[19189280]
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:37 13 -> socket:[19189281]
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 3 -> /run/shm/spork_8902
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 4 -> socket:[19184133]
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 5 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:38 6 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:37 7 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:37 8 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 May 14 16:37 9 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
```

The sockets have been opened read-only (fds #12/13 here).

I'm not doing anything in my code to change file permissions, and valgrind doesn't indicate anything untoward memory-access wise.  Does anyone know off the top of their head what could cause this?

Comment: You're seeing the permissions, not how the sockets were opened. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @gct: I don't think the permissions on `/proc/[pid]/fd` entries for sockets that have been created through `socketpair` matters in any way whatsoever, and thus it may well be that they simply aren't well-defined. Do the permissions affect your program behavior in any meaningful way?

Comment: @Dolda2000 They do, because I'm using the path in /proc to pass the socket to another process.  I might have to just fchmod them myself.

Comment: @gct: I have admittedly not tried, but I don't really think you can pass sockets to another process in that way regardless of permissions. What method are you using to try and pass them around? Also, may I suggest using `SCM_RIGHTS` instead?

Comment: @Dolda2000 it certainly works for pipes, which is all a socketpair socket really is, so I think it will work once I get the permissions issue figured out.  I'm trying to pass them as files for a library I'm replacing which is a popen() replacement.

Comment: @gct: Pipes and sockets are implemented quite differently, though, so just because something works for a pipe, I would not bet it works for a socket. Even for pipes, I don't think that opening them via `/proc/[pid]/fd` is a well-defined mechanism, but rather one that kinda just happens to work.

Comment: Just to expand on that, I've noticed myself that opening deleted files via `/proc/[pid]/fd` has worked on some kernel versions but not on others, which makes me think that it's a behavior that the kernel "tries to be nice about", but doesn't guarantee.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a closer look at what guarantees (if any) it gives.

Comment: @gct: Is there a reason you're not using an Unix domain socket to pass the socket descriptors, as Dolda2000 alteady suggested?

Comment: If it's a `popen()` replacement, can't you simply let the new process inherit the sockets, as usual? If not, I would, again, suggest using `SCM_RIGHTS` instead. That's a well-defined and documented mechanism.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I'm trying to make a library that will work with any program that expects a filename, so that a special API doesn't have to be used to open the inputs/outputs.  If I let the process inherit the file descriptors, I'm either limited to stdin/stdout or the process has to use a special API call to open the pipe...  My goal might not be achievable, and I might have to pass them through a socket as Dolda2000 suggests.

Comment: @gct: Or, alternatively, you could use a named pipe in conjunction with a dedicated detached process (spawned by the process that opened the socket in the first place), that acts as a proxy between the named pipe and the socket.

Comment: @gct: If you want to have pipe-like functionality that is opened via file-system paths, then named pipes are probably what you want. See `mkfifo(3)`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal That's an excellent idea, because I do have a separate process responsible for cleaning up and tee()-ing data so I can have multi-reader pipes, it'd be simple to put those in a temp directory instead of the proc file system...   Only catch there is I don't think I can have a named socket can I?  So I'd be limited to one-way pipes, so no "rw" mode like popen has.

Comment: @gct: Unfortunately, yes, there are no "named sockets", and named pipes are simplex only. It is indeed a fair bit "weird" that bound and listening UNIX sockets can't be opened via `open(2)`, but that's how it is.

Comment: @gct: How about using a [pseudoterminal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_openpt.3.html) instead of a named pipe? They are definitely full duplex. Your separate process worker would still need to transfer data between the pseudoterminal (master end) and the socket. The slave end of the pseudoterminal does have a filesystem path, and you can set the initial [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) settings for the pseudoterminal to do no CR/LF translation etc.

Comment: I hadn't heard of pseudoterminals before, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions on a socket only affect processes that try to connect to the socket after it has been created. `socketpair()` connects the process to the sockets as it's creating them, so the permissions have no effect at that time. Making them read-only prevents new connections to the sockets, which is appropriate since it's supposed to be a private communication by the process that created the pair and any processes it passes them to.

This is similar to the way permissions work when you create a new file. You can write:

```
open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0400);
```

to create a file that has read-only permissions, but open it in write mode. The permissions only affect later attempts to open the file, not the operation that creates the file -- it always gets access to the file.

Comment: I see the permissions change depending on when I open the socketpair though, is it something that's undefined?  I'm actually trying to explicitly pass the socket ends to another process via the filesystem.

Comment: Can you call `fchmod()` on the socket FDs?

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on when I open the socketpair"?

Comment: I'll see if I can change the permissions.  I tried moving around when in the program I open the sockets, before or after other files and depending on where I put it, the sockets get different permissions...

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it inherits the permissions from a previous use of that FD#, but that seems crazy.

Comment: That might be what's going on, I'll have to track more closely what files are opened before it...

Comment: I suspect they didn't think that the permissions mattered, because `socketpair` creates sockets without putting them in the filesystem. `/proc` is intended for diagnostic tools like `ps` and `lsof`, not as a way to pass streams via the filesystem.